# How can I stop PhpStorm to insert linebreaks between XML nodes when formatting?

Tags: xml, phpstorm

I have the following XML (from Magento 2):

```
<item name="address-list" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/list</item>
      <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">address-list</item>
</item>
```

When I use the automatic code format function I get the following:

```
<item name="address-list" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component"
              xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/list
        </item>
        <item name="displayArea"
              xsi:type="string">address-list
        </item>
</item>
```

This is no longer working, because Magento interprets the spaces between the tags, for example, the component becomes

```
"Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/list                               "
                                               ^^^^^ Unwanted spaces ^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I make PhpStorm stop to insert those linebreaks?

**Edit**

Demo File:

https://gist.github.com/amenk/c018332373045e3e8b13

Before formatting

[image]

After formatting:

[image]

Settings:

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide: 1) whole sample file (so I can download and try locally) -- should be as close to real one as possible (as some nuances may get lost and it may start working fine here) 2) screenshot of how it actually looks on your computer. So far I think it could be because or right margin -- with your settings IDE splits too long lines into multiple. If so then increasing right margin may be the way to go. Other than that: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | XML -> Other`

Comment: Okay, increasing the margin works...

Comment: Cool. Now please show screenshot of `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | XML -> Other` (that's, of course, if you will not be happy with increasing the right margin solution and would like it to work regardless of its value). I can compare with my settings (where right margin does not really means anything for xml files).

Comment: Updated... In the preview of the settings it does not seem to do this mistake. When pressing Ctrl-Alt-L it does.

Comment: The solution seems to be in `Warp attributes` option value -- please try `Do not wrap` instead of yours `Wrap if long` (that's with default/smaller right margin)

Comment: This seems to affect only the attributes insert the tags - not the text between the tags.

Comment: This is what I have here -- it does not reformat the text (in other words: it makes no changes if I manually call code reformat action): 1) http://postimg.org/image/pwndgcbh7/ 2) http://postimg.org/image/5mcv7xs4t/

Comment: Seems to work now. Must have done another mistake. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Based on your description and screenshots: looks like you have it wrapped because of right margin (the value is too low for your lines and IDE splits such long lines into few).

   The easiest solution is to just **increase right margin** (in current IDE versions it's possible to do this on per file type/language basis, as long it has entry in Code Style). In your case it will be at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | XML | Other`
2. In addition you may change your code style settings to prevent such wrapping even if line is longer than current right margin. For that look at **"Wrap attributes" option** at the same settings page -- use `Do not wrap` instead of yours `Wrap if long`.

   This setting seem to work fine on my setup:

   [image]

   [image]