# How to resolve this in phpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, code-editor

I have a problem with PhpStorm. When creating a reformat the code, the result is a disaster.

Example: this code.

```
<#if realm.rememberMe && !usernameEditDisabled??>
                            <div flex-xs flex="50">
                                <#if login.rememberMe??>
                                    <md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-checked="valueby" ng-click="checkedIf(value)">${msg("rememberMe")}</md-checkbox>
                                    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" ng-checked="valueby" ng-click="checkedIf(value)" name="rememberMe" tabindex="3"/>
                                    <#else>
                                    <md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-checked="value" ng-click="checkedIf(value)">${msg("rememberMe")}</md-checkbox>
                                    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" ng-checked="value" ng-click="checkedIf(value)" name="rememberMe" tabindex="3"/>
                                </#if>
                            </div>
                        </#if>
```

Reformatting is as follows:

```
<#if realm.rememberMe && !usernameEditDisabled??>
                            <div flex-xs flex="50">
                                <#if login.rememberMe??>
                                    <md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-checked="valueby"
                                                 ng-click="checkedIf(value)">${msg("rememberMe")}
                                    </md-checkbox>
                                    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" ng-checked="valueby"
                                           ng-click="checkedIf(value)" name="rememberMe" tabindex="3"/>
                                    <#else>
                                        <md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-checked="value"
                                                     ng-click="checkedIf(value)">${msg("rememberMe")}
                                        </md-checkbox>
                                        <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" ng-checked="value"
                                               ng-click="checkedIf(value)" name="rememberMe" tabindex="3"/>
                                </#if>
                            </div>
                        </#if>
```

The problem here:

line:

```
<input type="checkbox" style="display: none" ng-checked="value" ng-click="checkedIf(value)" name="rememberMe" tabindex="3"/>
```

phpStorm reformated:

```
<input type="checkbox" style="display: none" 
              ng-checked="value"
              ng-click="checkedIf(value)"
              name="rememberMe" 
              tabindex="3"/>
```

I want to keep everything in one line.

Comment: What did you want to happen?

Comment: Similar to the following question .. just for HTML language -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/33356277/783119

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps :

- the soft Wraps option PHPStorm in Editor > General
- the surround template : [Surround template](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/wrapping-a-tag-example-of-applying-surround-live-templates.html)